# Create Django Session From Token

Tags: angularjs, django, session, nginx, django-rest-framework

**The Problem**

I'm currently battling the well-known problem of serving authentication-enforced media files from Django. The background of the problem is simple:

- We want to use Django's Media File support
- Media files are not private by default. In fact, normally the webserver serves them directly.
- We want to authenticate users when accessing media files
- We are using token authentication on the front end
- Since there is no valid session, the browser can't authenticate when accessing the private files (such as opening a PDF in a new tab)
- We want Django to provide authentication for the browser, but need to somehow authenticate using the existing auth token
- We still want nginx to send the file back, so we will leverage the `X-Accel-Redirect` after authentication.

**Attempts To Solve**

What I've done so far (and it works) is create another API view that requires token authentication and sends the file back, then created an Angular directive to swap out all protected URLs with a blob. When the user clicks a link, it gets the file using token authentication, then creates a blob that contains that data. The browser then opens that blob.

Unfortunately, blobs cannot be shared, so users cannot paste links to each other for these files. I'm wondering if there is a way around it.

**Goal**

My goal is to use the token to create a valid (and short expiring) session. That way, when the user clicks a link, a request is sent checking if there is a valid session, and then *somehow* configures the browser so that it can use that session. The whole process will look like this:

- User clicks link (which is actually a more complex angular directive)
- Angular fires request for session to server
- Server responds with necessary information
- Use JavaScript to configure browser session
- Force browser to open link with newly established session
- Validate user based on session, use header to pass over sending of file to nginx

I'm not looking for an implemented answer, I can handle the fine details myself. I'm more interested in getting feedback as to how this could be done in the best way. Namely:

- How can I configure the browser given some session information in an API response?
- How should I handle expiring these sessions so that it is secure
- How should I establish this session? Is it reasonable to check/create the session each time a link is clicked (assume traffic is not a problem here)
- Is this a reasonable, cross browser solution? Is there some better way?
- How can I use an intermediate page to establish this session when the file URL is shared with a user who has no session but has a valid token?

**Some Options**

Update: I've spoken with some colleagues that have brought up the following options:

- Instead of a session, have the API retrieve a single use or short-expiring token and append it to the URL of the file as a query parameter. Validate this inside the request. This works, but still does not allow the URLs to be shared.
- Establish a session at the time of login. If that session is expired when a user tries to access a file, redirect to a session login, then when authenticated, redirect back to the file. This works too, but I want to avoid an extra authentication step, since tokens have a long expiry and sessions have a short one. Giving them the same expiry will also have drawbacks, as tokens that expire more often or sessions that expire less often are not ideal.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Sharing files between users? Should the user be logged in before accessing the files? And what are the rules/conditions for sharing the link/files? Is the user able/allowed to share every file? Who can access what files and how are the permissions set for each file?

Comment: Users must be logged in to see files. They will normally be logged in beforehand, otherwise will be redirected to login. All users can see all files. Goal is to authenticate while still allowing users to paste links to other users. Authenticating is easy (as mentioned in the question). The problem is authenticating and still allowing sharing.

Comment: If the user must be logged in to see the files, what is preventing you from validating each user before accessing the file?What is still not 100% clear to me is the `authenticate while still allowing users to paste links to other users`. Authenticate what? The user? Th user is already logged in right? And what is the `paste links to other users`? Pasting where? For what purpose? Isnt the login required for every user to access the files?

Comment: The user is "logged in" using token auth. The token is sent as a header in every API request. When a document (like a PDF) opens in a new tab, the browser does not have that token. The browser would need a valid session, which is a different type of authentication entirely. No session is established, so the user is not authenticated when a file opens in a new tab. Pasting links to users is necessary to share files. If user A has a file that they want to show user B, for example, they may email a URL. Both users will have to be authenticated to see it.

Comment: I think you are too concerned with details of the problem that are not really relevant. For example, the only reason I mention pasting is to demonstrate the limitations of a blob. The question is simple - how should I establish a browser session when users are naturally authenticated using tokens, such that the browser may request a file resource that is private. The browser cannot use the token that is normally used, because I can't modify default headers for outbound requests sent by the browser - only those sent via Ajax. Are you familiar with token-based authentication?

Comment: What is not clear to me, on one hand you just want to pass a token around, on the other hand, you are looking to create a session for the browser. As you know, session can be created without the user having to provide username and password. If you have a signed token that you are passing around, do you store it somewhere in user profile/logs etc? Assuming the signed token has been created upon a user authentication?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110559/discussion-between-jamie-counsell-and-waybehind).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply put the Token into a cookie.

That way, it will be send to the server automatically by the browser, and you could use it for authentication when the user accesses a downloadable file directly.

Instead of reading the `Authorization:` header, tell your Django middleware to read the token string from the cookie.

Comment: Since tokens expire less often than normal sessions, is there any security implications to this? The cookie may be present for a longer time. I feel like if the only case this is used is when authenticating for file viewing, it should be okay. Is this a safe assumption? SSL is used everywhere on the site.

Comment: You could set the `expires` value of the cookie for a short time only, so that it disappears a certain time after being set. But then again, you may be storing the token string in the client's localStorage anyway, so an attacker with access to the machine would be able to read the token from there too.

Comment: The [second half of this text compares](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/) the security pros and cons of using cookies or header tokens.

Comment: So it would almost make sense for me to switch to cookies, but I want to avoid worrying about CSRF. In that case, I could just require all API endpoints to have auth in the header, and all others to have auth in a cookie. Is it reasonable to use both?

Comment: Django and Angular have CSRF protection built-in for state-changing (POST, PUT, DELETE) requests.

Comment: Great. I will look into this! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to have more information about this topic.

I also get a token from django but everytime i refresh the page the user as to login again. i would like to keep it in a cookie to let the user make requests even if he closes the browser.

I also want to secure it with csrf protection but i dont know how to do it.
also, having the token as plain text in a cookie is it secure?
I have a lot of doubt about this process.

I am using django as backend API and reactjs as frontend.

How to make django generate the cookie and the csrf cookie?

1) I want to be able to use the token to authenticate from the browser to my website (

2) I want to use this api for a mobile app as well? so creating a cookie, does it create a conflict during the mobile app authentication?

Comment: This is not a real answer, you are actually asking questions... See [the How To Answer section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)